visible solid angle of the moon
I'm reading an astronomy textbook for high schoolers, it contains an exercise to calculate the visible angle ratio of the moon in the sky (the textbook is not in english so my terminology is probably wrong). The textbook also provides the answer, but I don't understand it.
The input for the exercise is the angle under which the moon is visible. It's specified that:
$$\varphi = 31'$$
The diameter of the moon is also named $D_l$.
The formula
$$dS = {r}^2 d\Omega$$
is explained; $r$ being the distance from the observer and $d\Omega$ being the solid angle.
The textbook provides the following solution, which I don't understand:
$$
dS = r^2d\Omega \implies \\ d\Omega=dS/r^2=\pi D_l^2/4r^2 = (\pi/4)\varphi^2= \pi/4 \times (31'/60' \times \pi/180)^2 \text{ sr} =6.39 \times 10^-{5} \text{ sr}
$$
I think it implies that:
$$
\varphi = D_l/r
$$
But I'm not sure. I'm also confused about the degree angles and the steradian solid angles. I struggled to find clear explanations elsewhere online, I would be interested in any relevant link assuming only trigonometry prior knowledge.

Welcome to Stack Exchange! I've made some formatting edits, but please feel free to adjust further. I am also confused by $$\varphi = 31°$$ can you add any further information or context about how that was introduced? Thanks!

It is using small angle approximation

Are you sure it’s not  = 31′ (minutes instead of degrees)?

Yeah I was gonna ask the same thing -- 31 degrees would be a VERY BIG MOON.

Yes, @PierrePaquette i should have written minutes and i corrected the post. thank you for your comment

What is "S"  ?..

In short, it is using small angle approximation.
Long answer:
From your equation:
$ds = r^2d\Omega$, (I believe $r$ is the distance between Earth and Moon)
You substitute:
$ds = \frac{\pi D_l^2}{4}$ into the equation and move $d\Omega$ to the other side to get:
$\Omega = \frac{\pi D_l^2}{4r^2}$
Note the angular diameter of the moon can be given by $tan$ function:
$tan \varphi = \frac{D_l}{r}$.
Because the apparent diameter of the Moon is so small, you can use the small angle approximation when you convert $\varphi$ into radian:
$tan \varphi \approx \varphi$
Thus you can get:
$tan^2 \varphi = \frac{D_l^2}{r^2} \approx \varphi^2$
Substitute the above equation back to:
$\Omega = \frac{\pi}{4}\varphi^2$
To convert $\varphi$ to radian, remember that $\pi$ radian $=$ $180$ degree.

I wasn't aware of the small angle approximation, that is what i was missing. It is clear now thank you!
